# Grouping of break points

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

I am working on a C# windows based project in visual studio 2005.I often debug different features in this huge project.Now the problem is i have made few break points in few places which i require only when i debug for that feature.i want other break points to be disabled then.I understand this might not be a use case for larger community.
What i want to know is,is there any way to group break points in VS 2005 ,so that i can enable disable them when i debug that particular feature?

Comment: You could probably do something fairly elaborate with conditional breakpoints, but firstly, do you know about the 'Breakpoints' window? It makes temporarily turning of breakpoints really trivial. You can't group them, but you can disable them easily, and just re-enable them via the same window.

Comment: Thanks Silky,i was not aware of this window,this will be quite usable for me(Though not exactly wht i was looking for)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's not a feature built into Visual Studio, however something I came across a while back is a clever use of macros to give some grouping functionality.

[Check out this blog entry by Jim Gries](http://blogs.msdn.com/jimgries/archive/2004/01/28/64153.aspx) showing how to do it.

Just a note, I now it doesn't help your current situation, but [the situation has been improved in VS 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/habibh/archive/2009/07/10/managing-breakpoints-in-visual-studio-2010-using-breakpoint-labels.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

this is now available in the latest Visual Studio 2022 Preview.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/streamlining-your-debugging-process-with-breakpoint-groups/

Answer (score 0):

you can check this reference:

[a VS 2010 Debugger Improvements (BreakPoints, DataTips, Import/Export)](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/vs-2010-debugger-improvements-breakpoints-datatips-import-export)

This solution works only in Visual Studio 2010 and above