# Visual Studio 2010 and break points

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, breakpoints

I am debugging my project, while debugging I have 2 sets of 'things' I need to monitor.
sometimes set A and sometime set B, for both sets i need different break points, can i gather the break points to groups and then disable/enable break point groups ?
Otherwise, i have to set each time the right breakpoints for each flow and then change them..

Thanks

Comment: You _could_ run two instances of VS

Comment: Yes I am aware of this, but since im working on VM it is slow enough i'd rather not run 2 instances :) tnx

Comment: Duplicate.  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181655/grouping-of-break-points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BreakPoints have `Labels`.

1. Start by setting a Label for each BreakPoint <kbd>Alt F9</kbd>+ <kbd>L</kbd> or `Right Click -> Edit Labels`.
2. Name them `SetA` and `SetB`
3. Use the Search textbox and type `SetB` - you'll only see the Breakpoints that match that label.
4. Now press the `Enable or Disable all breakpoints matching the current search criteria` button.
   Only those breakpoints will get enabled.

Now just by typing SetA or SetB in the TextBox you can Enable/Disable the entire group

Notice you also have  Export and Import buttons so you can save theses settings and reload them whenever you want.